# Copy with hidden colums and filtered rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

i have a problem with copy Data from a Range into another Sheet. In the Copy Range are some hidden Columms and filtered rows.
With my Code ist only copy the visible Coluumms and rows into the nother sheet but i should copy all Data from the Range into the other sheet.

My Code that copy only the visible Data is

```
Worksheets("ANSICHT Komponente").Range("ANSICHT_Komponenten_Kostenanteil").Copy
'Einfügen auf dem Temp Daten Blatt
Worksheets("Temp_Daten").Range("B5:R56").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
      Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Hope u can help me that it will Copy all Data in the Range.

Thx Trekschaf

Comment: Not sure if there is a parameter to add to the copy method to ask it to copy hidden cells but you could always programmatically unhide the cells, copy, and then hide again.

Comment: Thx, that was one way I also thought about but i dident like it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table with hidden rows/columns and you want to copy/pastespecial to another worksheet and to copy **all** the data, you must do it cell-by-cell.  Say we have on *Sheet1:*

[image: before]

Running this:

```
Sub try_1_by_1()
    Dim pets As Range
    Set pets = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D20")
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In pets
        addy = r.Address
        r.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range(addy).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
    Next r
End Sub
```

will transfer the entire range regardless of the filtering.

The loop can be avoided if you use a direct transfer rather then **Copy**

```
Sub try_another()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:D20")
    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D20")
    r2.Value = r1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: thx
this way i found before but i i hoped there would by a easy way.